# plt.plot() showing X's on points, how to have just the line?

Tags: matplotlib

```
plt.plot(K, distortions, 'bx-')
plt.xlabel('k')
plt.ylabel('Distortion')
plt.title('The Elbow Method showing the optimal k')
plt.show()
```

My Elbow Method plot above is showing X's on each point, which makes the plot visually difficult to interpret.

How do I have just the line?

[image: elbow with xs]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove options in plot 'bx-', x at least